# How does \if \else work at \DeclareDocumentCommand?

Tags: math-mode, macros, conditionals, text-mode

I made a command with `DeclareDocumentCommand` from the packet `xparse`, and I have had troubles. My problem is that the `\ifmmode` (if mathmode) and the `else` don't work correctly, because when I type `$$ \num{}[] $$`, it shows the things that are in `\ifmmode` and `\else`.

[image: imagen_1]

Here is part of the code

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\num}{m o o}{
    \ifmmode
        \text{mathmode}
        \IfValueT{#1}{\text{#1}}
        \IfValueT{#2}{
            \IfNoValueTF{#3}{
                \,\text{#2}
            }
        }
    \else
        \text{textmode}
        \IfValueT{#1}{#1}
        \IfValueT{#2}{
            \IfValueT{#3}{#2/#3}
            %\, % Espacio
            \IfNoValueTF{#3}{\ \text{#2}}
        }
    \fi
}
```

Comment: *Don't* use `\DeclareDocumentCommand`; it would silently override existing commands; in particular `\num` is defined by `siunitx`.

Comment: And what command should I use?

Comment: `\NewDocumentCommand` is the right choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used `\IfNoValueTF` but only provided one branch where two were expected.  You probably meant to use `\IfNoValueT`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\num}{m o o}{%
    \ifmmode
        \text{mathmode}%
        \IfValueT{#1}{\text{#1}}%
        \IfValueT{#2}{%
            \IfNoValueT{#3}{% <<< T instead of TF
                \,\text{#2}%
            }%
        }%
    \else
        \text{textmode}%
        \IfValueT{#1}{#1}%
        \IfValueT{#2}{%
            \IfValueT{#3}{#2/#3}%
            %\, % Espacio
            \IfNoValueT{#3}{\ \text{#2}}% <<< T instead of TF
        }%
    \fi
}
\begin{document}
\[ \num{}[] \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you!! you are so great

Comment: The last two tests can be incorporated in a single `\IfNoValueTF`. Besides, it makes no sense to do `\IfValueT{#1}`, because it's a mandatory argument.

Comment: @egreg you are right